# How to remove an item from DevExpress LookupEdit?

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I'm using the DevExpress LookupEdit control in my C# application. How do I remove the selected item from the LookupEdit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the item from the underlying DataSource.